# Unable to draw multiple circles and move them on x axis

Tags: arrays, encoding, processing

I'm having troubles with my arrays in processing. When I run my code, there is only one circle drawn even though the array has a value of 3. But the the circles also don't move from right to left either. When I don't use an array, the code works so I'm not sure if I've put the wrong things in the wrong place or if I'm missing something. I would appreciate anyone's help.

```
int[] nums = new int [3];
float circleX;
float circleY;

void setup(){
 size(500,500);
 for(int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
 nums[i] = int(random(0,400));  
circleX = 460;
circleY = random(40,460);
}
}

void draw(){
 background(0);
 stroke(255);
 strokeWeight(4);
 noFill();
 for(int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++){
  ellipse(circleX,circleY,80,80); 
  circleX = circleX - 1;
  noLoop();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution below. If you want three random circles then create arrays of the x,y coordinates.

```
int _num = 3;
float[] circleX = new float[_num];
float[] circleY = new float[_num];

void setup(){
 size(500,500);
 for(int i = 0; i< _num; i++){ 
  circleX[i] = random(0,400);
  circleY[i] = random(40,460);
 }
 noLoop();
}

void draw(){
 background(0);
 stroke(255);
 strokeWeight(4);
 noFill();
 for(int i = 0; i <_num;i++){
   ellipse(circleX[i],circleY[i],80,80); 
   circleX[i] = circleX[i] - 1;   
 }
}
```